# Android DialogPreference width

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a custom `DialogPreference` that just contains a date picker. Everything works fine EXCEPT the dialog has a huge border and title around it as can be seen below.

[image]

I would like the dialog to just be the date picker:

[image]

I've figured out how to remove the title by setting the window title to null, but the massive border still exists.

My custom layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <DatePicker 
        android:id="@+id/birthdayPicker"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried setting the linear layouts width/height to `wrap_content`, setting negative margins, and a host of other hackey solutions but nothing seems to be working.

The only luck I've had so far is overriding `onShow` and programmatically setting the windows size to some arbitrary amount - like a width of 300dp. This is obviously super duper hackey and I'd prefer a more elegant solution. Any help would be much appreciated guys!

Comment: Why does your `LinearLayout` has `match_parent` for both width and height?

Comment: maybe a `wrap_content` for your LinearLayout `layout_width`?

Comment: I'm currently finding the same problem, with a TimePicker instead of a DatePicker. Did you ever find a solution to this? Would you mind sharing the `onShow` hack?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Your `LinearLayout` should not be `match_parent` but `wrap_content` eg the `DatePicker`'s dimensions.

Try:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <DatePicker 
        android:id="@+id/birthdayPicker"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that with no luck - match_parent vs wrap_content seems to make no difference.